# Deploying DR enabled web application on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I have a Web Application backed up with a database. (Actually I have 2 Virtual Machines. Linux for app PHP & MySQL and another Windows Server for ASP.Net & Sql Server) Currently it is deployed on a Virtual Machine (Single Tier) on Windows Azure. For Disaster Recovery the application needs to be decoupled. Meaning Code, files/folders and database should be separate.
Please help me to understand
1. Do I need to have 2 Virtual Machines for Code & Database and a Storage to store files?
2. If yes then what amount of code do I need to change?
3. Can you suggest a tutorial which will guide me to setup Disaster Recovery?
4. Do I need to keep anther instance running one for code & other for Database?
5. If yes, then how do I make sure that code and database both are in Sync?

Answer (score 0):

You need to plan for high availability and disaster recovery at both the database and application level.

- For the database, you need mirroring/replication of some sort for both your MySQL and SQL Server databases (not clear from your post if you have two apps one using MySQL and the other using SQL Server). For these, depending on the configuration, you might need to have two or more virtual machines to enable replication. Look at these articles for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html) and [SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj870962.aspx).
- If you are looking at options (and can re-architect), look at [SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) on Azure which has built in redundancy.
- The virtual machines will have to be grouped into [availability sets](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/) to ensure redundancy.
- This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn251004.aspx) sheds more light and would be a good starting point to understand how to architect applications on Azure.